# Objective-C- animateWithDuration Completion block called early

Tags: objective-c, ios8

Before you discredit this question as being asked before, please look at the details:

I have a simple animation of shrinking the frame of a view from it's normal size to a zero frame in the middle of the superview. In my completion block I remove the superview from its superview and remove the view controller from the parent view controller. The completion block is called immediately. Moreover, the `BOOL` parameter `finished` to the completion block equals `YES`. So when I check if the animation is finished it says that it is even when it's not and the view is prematurely removed. Here is my code:

```
- (void)closeWindow {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     contentView.frame = [self getSchoolSetUpStartingFrame];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     if(finished) {
                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [self removeFromParentViewController];
                     }

                 }];
 }


- (CGRect)getSchoolSetUpStartingFrame {
    CGRect startingFrame;
    CGRect myFrame = self.view.frame;

    float xPos = (myFrame.origin.x + (myFrame.size.width/2));
    float yPos = (myFrame.origin.y + (myFrame.size.height/2));

    startingFrame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);

    return startingFrame;
}
```

Is there anything else that could be related to this problem that I haven't considered yet? I appreciate all the help.

Comment: You should explain your controller setup. Is this code in a child view controller? What is contentView?

Comment: are you using auto-layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing the animation duration to `.5f`, and verify that `contentView` is not nil during the animation block.

Also, it might be easier to achieve this animation by using a transform

```
animations:^{
                 contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.1f, .1f);

             }
```